# How to generate random nvarchars in sql server

Tags: sql-server, random, sql-server-2014

I have created a stored procedure by the help of some links on this site as below:
[How to insert Huge dummy data to Sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481702/how-to-insert-huge-dummy-data-to-sql-server)
[What is the most efficient way to generate 8 character random alphanumeric string in TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934330/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-generate-8-character-random-alphanumeric-strin)

My stored procedure:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DUMMY_INSERT]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE  DUMMY_INSERT
END
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE DUMMY_INSERT (
@noOfRecords INT
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @r varchar(8)

SELECT @r = coalesce(@r, '') +CHAR(
CASE WHEN r between 0 and 9 THEN 48
WHEN r between 10 and 35 THEN 55
ELSE 61 END + r)
FROM
master..spt_values
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT CAST(RAND(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))) *61 as int) r) a
WHERE type = 'P' AND number < 8

DECLARE @count int
SET @count = 1;

WHILE (@count < @noOfRecords)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Tbl_Customer(name)
     VALUES(@r);

     SET @count = @count + 1;
END
END
```

When execution, it will insert `@noOfRecords` (given by user) records with **Same** names generated as `@r`. How can I make `@r` **different** random nvarchar for each generated record.

Comment: Are you trying to find a way to generate random string or you want to debug the provided code. There are many other ways to achieve that goal.

Comment: Always mention the version of db or software your are using

Comment: I am trying to insert for example 100000 different names in a table. I want to work with sql performances and need big data in my tables.

Comment: I am working with MS SQL Server 2014

Comment: Just move the `select @r = ...` inside the `while`.

Comment: Is it important that you use the full range of `a-zA-Z`? To generate an 8 character random alpha numeric string you can just use `CONVERT(CHAR(8),CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4),2)` which is much simpler though has fewer permutations (as only uses hex characters)

Comment: @Blorgbeard, the result is the same as original SP. It produce **same** names.

Comment: @Martin Smith , thank. It has solved the problem.

Comment: But, Is there any solution to insert just characters and NOT digits?

Answer (score 0):

Try to adapt for your neednesses the following snippet:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.DUMMY_INSERT', N'P') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE dbo.DUMMY_INSERT;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DUMMY_INSERT(@noOfRecords INT, @chars INT = 8) AS
WITH
  cc AS(SELECT 1 c UNION ALL SELECT c + 1 FROM cc WHERE c < @chars),
  rr AS(SELECT 1 r UNION ALL SELECT r + 1 FROM rr WHERE r < @noOfRecords),
  rc AS(SELECT r, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 61 rnd FROM rr CROSS JOIN cc)
  SELECT
    (SELECT NCHAR(IIF(rnd < 10, 48, IIF(rnd < 36, 55, 61))) [text()]
     FROM rc WHERE rc.r = rr.r
     FOR XML PATH('')) rndrow
  FROM rr;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Tbl_Customer', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Tbl_Customer;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tbl_Customer(name NVARCHAR(30));
GO
INSERT dbo.Tbl_Customer(name) EXEC dbo.DUMMY_INSERT 20;
GO
SELECT name FROM dbo.Tbl_Customer;
```